# Confused with JSON data and normal data in Django ajax request

Tags: json, jquery, django-models, django-templates

I read about JSON from internet but still i have not got the grasp of it. I am reading this article

http://webcloud.se/log/AJAX-in-Django-with-jQuery/

I could not understood the first part where the function is using JSON

```
def xhr_test(request, format):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if format == 'xml':
            mimetype = 'application/xml'
        if format == 'json':
            mimetype = 'application/javascript'
        data = serializers.serialize(format, ExampleModel.objects.all())
        return HttpResponse(data,mimetype)
    # If you want to prevent non XHR calls
    else:
        return HttpResponse(status=400)
```

My Main Problems are

1. From where the function is getting `format` variable
2. Does format is `json` mean that data given to function is json or data which will be recived is json
3. Can anyone give me simple example that what will be the ouput of this function
   `data = serializers.serialize(format, ExampleModel.objects.all())`
4. How will I use that data when i get that response in jquery function
5. If i don't use JSON in above function then how will the input and response back will chnage

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. From where the function is getting format variable

In practice, there are lots of ways this format could be populated.  HTTP provides an `Accept:` header that requests can use to indicate the preferred `Content-Type` for the response.  On the client, you might use `xhr.setRequestHeader('accept', 'application/json')` to tell the server that you want your response in json format.  In practice, though, very few frameworks actually do this.  This being django, arguments to view functions are usually set in the urlconf, you might craft a urlconf like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', 
    # ...
    (r'^xhr_test.(?<format>.*)$', 'path.to.xhr_test'),
)
```

> 2 . Does format is json mean that data given to function is json or data which will be recived is json

This particular view doesn't do anything at all with the request body, and is certainly providing a response body in the supplied `format`

> 4 . How will I use that data when i get that response in jquery function

Depending on how complicated your request needs to be, you can use `jQuery.getJSON`, which will pass your callback with regular JavaScript objects that result from parsing the JSON.  If you need to do a bit more work to get the request right, you can use `jQuery.parseJSON` to process the json data, and that will return the same JavaScript objects.

Answer (score 0):

1. From the urlconf, just like it says in the article right below it.
2. The query set will be serialized as JSON.
3. It will be the query set represented as either XML or JSON. `python manage.py shell` is your friend.
4. You will decode it, then iterate over it.
5. You'll need to find some other format to serialize it in instead.

Comment: Actually I want to look at sample example of points 3,4,5 so that I can better understand. If thats too much then you can point some internet resource. I have felt that i need to ask more questions in SO in order to understand ur single line answers :)

Comment: Number 3 shows you how to get an example of it. Number 4 is a call to the decoding library and a `for` loop. Number 5 stands on its own; if you don't know any other serialization formats then I recommend you put it out of mind.

Comment: Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams  Please dont mind , but i have seen many times that your answers are stopping someone to give detailed answers. I am not saying that ur answers r wrong , but sometime users asking question are very dumb like me which need detailed explanation. Once you give answer , no one adds more answers , as they all respect ur repuataion. I beleive TokenGuy would have given explanation on point 3,5 but he did't because he didn't want to oppose you.